# macOS: Is there a way to access the window controller without crashing?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4, nswindowcontroller

I have to access the windowController by doing this

```
let windowController = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.windowController as! WindowController
```

as soon as I try to run this inside `viewDidAppear`, the app crashes with this

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

The solution, as I found on the web, is to add this line before accessing the windowController:

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

This line makes the app active.

But this method does not solve anything for real, because if another app becomes the front app while my app is loading, my app crashes.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: (1) If you don't want to crash the application, don't force-unwrap a variable.  (2) You are doing it at a wrong lines.  The view controller does not know about its window controller before it appears.

Comment: care to create an answer telling me how o do it? I need the code to be executed, not skipped if the controller is nil.

Comment: IDK how to say this without sounding like a dick, but from the questions of yours that I've been seeing recently, it's been increasingly apparent to me that you would greatly benefit from a comprehensive and structured resource, like a course or a big fat book. I'm all for the "hacker way," but you seem to be struggling from the downfalls of cobbling together bits and pieces of learning, rather than having one full complete course experience

Comment: There are certain things that I never saw a book covering. Things like this question. Things like why you don't have a window controller load with its own view controller is already displayed during viewDidAppear (yes, I said viewDidLoad by mistake). This thing is beyond reason. Think about it: a window controller owns a viewController, this view controller is displayed and yet the window controller is nil if the app is not in focus. This is insanity from whatever created this.

Comment: @SpaceDog I can't cite any examples, but I would be surprised if a good book on iOS/macOS development didn't cover things like the view controller life cycle, window life cycle, weak references, etc. "This thing is beyond reason." Not even close. You don't understand it yet, but that doesn't mean it's beyond reason. AppKit has been designed by *many*, very high skilled, very well paid engineers, who made it this way for a reason. Not to employ the naturalistic fallacy, but rest assured that the software engineers working on AppKit are top notch.

Comment: "a window controller owns a viewController"  *Eventually,* but first the ViewController needs to initialized and configured (by the storyboard). `viewDidLoad` is called for you in the middle of that process. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434476-viewdidload): "Called after the view controller’s view has been loaded into memory.". What you need is [`viewDidAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434415-viewwillappear): "Called when the view controller’s view is fully transitioned onto the screen."

Comment: The view life cycle is briefly described in the [`NSViewController` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller), and if further described in [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) - Working with View Controllers § Understand the View Controller Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3)

Comment: Furthermore, you should be clued into the possible non-availability of the windowController by its optionality. Some ObjC APIs that were automatically imported into Swift come with an unnecessary optionality ([`UILabel.text`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620538-text), for example). However, others are optional for a reason. Without knowing the particular API, you should always assume the optionality is intentional, and not force unwrap.

Comment: This is not the problem. I have tried to use a delegate call back, viewDidAppear, etc.. The moment the app is not active, NSApp.mainWindow is nil.

Comment: @Alexander AppKit has its quirks. It feels like some parts were ported from iOS by engineers who weren't familiar with AppKit.

Comment: @Willeke this plus a documentation written by satan, results is a lot of waste time and workarounds.

Comment: @SpaceDog Ah my bad, I thought you were accessing `NSView.window`. The documentation of [`NSApp.mainWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428723-mainwindow) is very clear: "The value in this property is nil when the app’s storyboard or nib file has not yet finished loading. It might also be nil when the app is inactive or hidden." AppKit certainly has its quirks, but this isn't one of them, and makes perfect sense, at least to me.

Comment: @SpaceDog If I recall correctly, the main window is the window that's currently selected, that's in the first responder chain (among other things, to make it the responder to menu bar items). If your app has multiple windows, and none of them are selected (i.e. your app is in the background), which one do you expect to be considered the "main" window?

Comment: What is the core problem you're trying to solve? Is it to access the window controller  corresponding to the window containing the view of your view controller?

Comment: @Alexander - I need to configure the windowController at run time, but if the mainWindow is nil I cannot. My app has only one window and one viewController at this time. I expect mainWindow to be the only window the app has.

Comment: "I expect mainWindow to be the only window the app has." don't rely on this. Even if it's true today, it might not be tomorrow, and you don't want a fragile solution to break at the change of such a simple thing. For one, `mainWindow` does not mean "the one window your app has". It means the "window that's currently in the first responder chain". When you app isn't selected, no windows meet that criteria, so you get the very obvious behaviour you might expect given those circumstances.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `yourVC.view.window`? Where did all this `NSApplication ` and main window nonsense come from?

Comment: both  gives the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198745/discussion-between-alexander-and-spacedog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller being loaded doesn't mean it's been presented on screen, or even situated within your window. So clearly, you can't do window-related code from `viewDidLoad`.

Instead, you should probably register an [`NSWindowDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate) to your window, but the best course of action depends heavily on exactly what you're trying to do with the window.

Comment: Like I was suspecting, your solution results in crash too. I have assigned a delegate method `windowDidBecomeMain` to do the task. When I try to access `NSApp.mainWindow` it is nil. I will try with other delegate methods.

Comment: NSApp.mainWindow becomes nil the moment the app loses focus. Unless I can keep the app active and prevent macOS from putting it on the background, I see no solution.